# Memory Error for 20-dimensional numpy matrix in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory

I tried to create a 20-dimensional numpy matrix in python:

```
C_shape=[]

for NOP_i in range(0,NOP):                   #NOP=15
    C_shape.append(mpar_val_points[NOP_i])   #mpar_val_points =[3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
C_shape.append (p_val_points)                #p_val_points=4
C_shape.append (wkat_val_points)             #wkat_val_points=4
C_shape.append (T_val_points)                #T_val_points=4
C_shape.append(t_val_points)                 #t_val_points=11
C_shape.append(NOC)                          #NOC=4 

C=np.zeros(C_shape)
```

I received the following error:

`MemoryError:`

I want to create a matrix filled with zeros and fill it with float values afterwards.

I have already installed the 64 bit Python version. Does anyone know how I can handle this problem? I already thought about creating some txt.files to save parts of the matrix..

Thank you!

Comment: You should show us `C_shape`, so we don't have to reconstruct it from you code.  But why do you need to construct such a high dimensional array?  Even if you construct it, could you use it?

Comment: What kind of `txt` file could handle such a shape?  Normally `csv` text files are just 2d - rows and columns.  Simply adding a third dimension, e.g 'planes' is awkward.   And how were you going to fill values with floats?  Any kind of iteration would take insanely long.   Practice with much smaller arrays before you try something large and complicated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, you are trying to create a 20 dimensional matrix of dimensions 3x3x3...x3x4x4x4x11x4 (spare me from writing the 15 '3's). Which amounts to 40406522112 elements within that matrix.

Assuming that each number only takes 1 byte (which is definitely not the case for floats, but lets use it as simplification) that makes 40406522112 bytes which is around 38 GB. If we consider that each number takes 64 bytes, we get 64 times the RAM mentioned before. I really doubt that your computer has that much RAM memory and so does numpy. That is the reason for numpy raising the error.

As for how to solve it, I can only think to process the matrix in chunks. And iterating a lot of times over that. It is likely to be slow and will require that you have enough space in your disk to write all those txt files for each chunk of the matrix.